# Getting count of count from a Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle SQL query that selects the count of the company from different department.

```
select 
                 a.cust_nm, 
                 a.cust_acct_nb, 
                 a.cust_company_nb, 
                 to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'YYYYMM'), 
                 count(*)
from 
                 customer a, case b
where 
                 a.cust_nb = b.case_cust_nb
                 and a.cust_company_nb in 
                     ('01062','01602','01603','01604','01605','01606')
                 and b.case_receive_dt > sysdate -365
                 and b.case_status_cd = 'CC'
group by 
                 a.cust_nm, 
                 a.cust_acct_nb, 
                 a.cust_company_nb, 
                 to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'YYYYMM')
order by 
                 a.cust_nm, 
                 a.cust_acct_nb, 
                 a.cust_company_nb, 
                 to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'YYYYMM')
```

This return the `count` of `a.cust_nm, a.cust_acct_nb, a.cust_company_nb, to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'YYYYMM')`

In the same query, I need one more count of all `cust_acct_nb`

Eg:-

```
cust_acct_nb    cust_acct_nb    cust_acct_nb   cust_acct_nb        count(*)    Final_Total
KFC                 1               12             09-10-1991         12
KFC                 1               12             10-10-1991         10     
KFC                 1               12             11-10-1991         10           32
KFC                 2               12             09-10-1991         12
KFC                 2               12             10-10-1991         10     
KFC                 2               12             11-10-1991         15           37
```

How can I get `Final_Total` in same query ?

Please help!!

Comment: Can you please post some sample post data?

Comment: You could create another view/subquery with the total data and join it to your actual query, but there will be a bit overhead. It seems easier to calculate total from the database client side, using the cursor

Comment: I can not use any client script, because it is used in one of the ETS called `Jitterbit`, it will just return you the result and loop it through.

Comment: I think that Running aggregates is what you're looking for: [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12096_01/books/admintool/admintool_SQL11.html](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12096_01/books/admintool/admintool_SQL11.html)

Comment: Anything to do will ROLLUP?

Comment: using Rollup, just replace your group by with: group by rollup(
                 a.cust_nm, 
                 a.cust_acct_nb, 
                 a.cust_company_nb, 
                 to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'YYYYMM')) having 
coalesce(
                 a.cust_nm, 
                 a.cust_acct_nb, 
                 a.cust_company_nb, 
                 to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'YYYYMM')) is null or coalesce(
                 a.cust_acct_nb, 
                 a.cust_company_nb, 
                 to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'YYYYMM')) is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery in the `select` statement as follows:

```
  select a.cust_nm,
         a.cust_acct_nb,
         a.cust_company_nb,
         to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'YYYYMM'),
         count(*),
         (select count(*)
            from customer a1, case b1
           where     a1.cust_nb = b1.case_cust_nb
                 and a1.cust_company_nb in ('01062','01602','01603','01604','01605','01606')
                 and b1.case_receive_dt > sysdate -365
                 and b1.case_status_cd = 'CC'
                 and a1.cust_acct_nb = a.cust_acct_nb)
    from customer a, case b
   where     a.cust_nb = b.case_cust_nb
         and a.cust_company_nb in ('01062','01602','01603','01604','01605','01606')
         and b.case_receive_dt > sysdate -365
         and b.case_status_cd = 'CC'
group by a.cust_nm,
         a.cust_acct_nb,
         a.cust_company_nb,
         to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'YYYYMM')
order by a.cust_nm,
         a.cust_acct_nb,
         a.cust_company_nb,
         to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'YYYYMM');
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
cust_acct_nb    cust_acct_nb    cust_acct_nb   cust_acct_nb        count(*)    Final_Total
KFC                 1               12             09-10-1991         12           32
KFC                 1               12             10-10-1991         10            32
KFC                 1               12             11-10-1991         10           32
KFC                 2               12             09-10-1991         12           37
KFC                 2               12             10-10-1991         10           37
KFC                 2               12             11-10-1991         15           37
```

Comment: Thanks, it works line a charm. One more question I have is, I do not want to order by name (`cust_acct_nb`). But If I remove it from `group by` clause, it send error because it is there in the select. What should I do for this ?

Comment: If you are using an aggregate function (e.g., `count`, `sum`, etc.) in your query then all the columns you are referring to in your `select` and `order by` clauses will also have to be included in the `group by` clause. Read more on Oracle Docs by googling for `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? I cant test it since I have no data setup.

```
select 
                 a.cust_nm, 
                 a.cust_acct_nb, 
                 a.cust_company_nb, 
                 to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'YYYYMM'), 
                 count(*)
from 
                 customer a, case b
where 
                 a.cust_nb = b.case_cust_nb
                 and a.cust_company_nb in 
                     ('01062','01602','01603','01604','01605','01606')
                 and b.case_receive_dt > sysdate -365
                 and b.case_status_cd = 'CC'
group by rollup
                 (a.cust_nm, 
                 a.cust_acct_nb, 
                 a.cust_company_nb, 
                 to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'YYYYMM'))
order by 
                 a.cust_nm, 
                 a.cust_acct_nb, 
                 a.cust_company_nb, 
                 to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'YYYYMM')
```

Comment: Where is the first count here ? Or count of count in select ?

Comment: second count is in roll up

Answer (score 0):

```
- Try This:

select 
             a.cust_nm,  
             a.cust_company_nb, 
             to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
             decode(grouping(a.cust_acct_nb),1,'Sum of group',a.cust_acct_nb), 
             count(*)
from 
             customer a, case b
where 
             a.cust_nb = b.case_cust_nb
             and a.cust_company_nb in 
                 ('01062','01602','01603','01604','01605','01606')
             and b.case_receive_dt > sysdate -365
             and b.case_status_cd = 'CC'
group by rollup(
             a.cust_nm, 
             a.cust_acct_nb, 
             a.cust_company_nb, 
             to_char(b.case_receive_dt, 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Oracle SQL gives you possibility to query totals and subtotals in one query with **ROLLUP** extension. Here is an example of such functionality:

```
SELECT fact_1_id,
   fact_2_id,
   SUM(sales_value) AS sales_value
FROM   dimension_tab
GROUP BY ROLLUP (fact_1_id, fact_2_id)
ORDER BY fact_1_id, fact_2_id;

 FACT_1_ID  FACT_2_ID SALES_VALUE
---------- ---------- -----------
     1          1     4363.55
     1          2     4794.76
     1          3     4718.25
     1          4     5387.45
     1          5     5027.34
     1               24291.35
     2          1     5652.84
     2          2     4583.02
     2          3     5555.77
     2          4     5936.67
     2          5     4508.74
     2               26237.04
                     50528.39
```

You can get more examples here http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets.php#rollup